# How to get list of all databases and its respective users list in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have searched online and found few queries where I can list users of current database but I want to return all databases and its respective users list in single query.

I am using SQL Server 2017.

How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of users for all instance's databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445444/how-to-get-a-list-of-users-for-all-instances-databases)

Answer (score 1):

Cursor to get database list -> Dynamic SQL to change database context and select from sys.database_principals in the respective database

You can also create a temp table beforehand and insert the result of the dynamic sql into it so you can return all results in a single set

Comment: If possible,Could you please provide me query.Thanks in advance.